# Concatenate two columns and paste to new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to concatenate two columns and paste them into another worksheet in the same workbook. There is a complication in that I have to do this for a predefined range of rows, not the whole column. I have managed to get one column copied over as follows, but I am not sure how to extend this to the concatenation of two columns.

```
Sub Write_Rows(StartRow As Integer, EndRow As Integer)

Dim CopySheet As Worksheet, PasteSheet As Worksheet
Set CopySheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set PasteSheet = Sheets("Master") 'I already made this sheet

CopySheet.Range("B" & StartRow, "B" & EndRow).Copy PasteSheet.Range("A2")

End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do is exactly like the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680126/concatenate-two-columns-of-cells-and-paste-values-to-new-column) but in Excel not Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: Is using an array formula an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via an array formula, then remove the formula and fix the values. Supposing you want to concatenate columns B and C:

```
Sub Write_Rows(StartRow As Integer, EndRow As Integer)

    Dim dest As Range: Set dest = Sheets("Master").Range("A2:A" & 2 + EndRow - StartRow)
    Dim src1 As Range: Set src1 = Sheet1.Range("B" & StartRow & ":B" & EndRow)
    Dim src2 As Range: Set src2 = src1.Offset(0, 1)

    dest.FormulaArray = "=" & src1.Address(External:=True) & "&" & src2.Address(External:=True)
    dest.Value = dest.Value

End Sub
```